# Using ec2_snapshot getting error message "boto required for this module"

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, ansible, boto

I am using Ubuntu Server 16.4 with ansible 2.4 on AWS

My playbook is trying to take snapshots of ec2 vol. See below

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: yes
  any_errors_fatal: True

- name: Take snapshots of all volume"
  ec2_snapshot:
      volume_id: "{{item.id}}"
      description: "Taken on {{ ansible_date_time.date }}"
      snapshot_tags:
          frequency: hourly
  with_items: "{{ aws_ec2_vol_setting }}"
```

I run the playbook with the following cmd

```
ansible-playbook -vvv  pb_aws_backup_nw_us_sat.yml

Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_snapshot.py
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: r_ansible
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/r_ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1517934063.54-197986659054036 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1517934063.54-197986659054036="` echo /home/r_ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1517934063.54-197986659054036 `" ) && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmprERpt_ TO /home/r_ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1517934063.54-197986659054036/ec2_snapshot.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/r_ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1517934063.54-197986659054036/ /home/r_ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1517934063.54-197986659054036/ec2_snapshot.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-ociuiywkpfvurbbesjwxhczxoglttlsa; /usr/bin/python /home/r_ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1517934063.54-197986659054036/ec2_snapshot.py; rm -rf "/home/r_ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1517934063.54-197986659054036/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"' && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_snapshot.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
  File "/tmp/ansible_gUIlz4/ansible_module_ec2_snapshot.py", line 127, in <module>
    import boto.ec2

failed: [localhost] (item={u'vol': u'vol-us-sat-01', u'id': u'vol-0b6aaa3b8289580f6', u'server': u'us-nv-sat-01'}) => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aws_access_key": null,
            "aws_secret_key": null,
            "description": null,
            "device_name": null,
            "ec2_url": null,
            "instance_id": null,
            "last_snapshot_min_age": 0,
            "profile": null,
            "region": null,
            "security_token": null,
            "snapshot_id": null,
            "snapshot_tags": {
                "frequency": "hourly"
            },
            "state": "present",
            "validate_certs": true,
            "volume_id": "vol-0b6aaXXXXXXXX",
            "wait": true,
            "wait_timeout": 0
        }
    },
    "item": {
        "id": "vol-0b6aXXXXXXXXXX",
        "server": "us-nv-sat-01",
        "vol": "vol-us-sat-01"
    },
    "msg": "boto required for this module"
}
```

Note: The access key and secret key are empty because i am using a IAM role that is assign to the server.

I have check my host and to me at least it looks like i have all the requirements.

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ pip list boto | grep boto
boto (2.48.0)
boto3 (1.5.23)
botocore (1.8.37)
$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
```

python modules all seem to be there and importing fine is well

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto
>>> import boto.ec2
>>> import boto3
```

So i am not sure why i am getting the error "boto required for this module".
I have also tried without any success the solution suggested [here](https://www.zigg.com/2014/using-virtualenv-python-local-ansible.html) but I still get the issue.

Comment: You execute task as `sudo`, please check that `boto` is visible under `root` account as well.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov thanks. This allowed me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case that the pip packages you are seeing somehow are not able to run properly with the default python that is installed (if you can run `sudo pip freeze | grep boto` you can see the full list of packages), if boto is not there maybe you'd need to install it using `sudo pip install`. On the other hand something I'd rather do is to set up a python virtual env and install all packages Ansible requires only in that isolated env, like:

Dependencies:

`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install virtualenv`

Then create the virtual env:

`virtualenv ansible_vEnv`

Activate the virtual env:

`source ansible_vEnv/bin/activate`

Then just install all python dependencies with pip for the ec2.py:

- boto > 2.45
- boto3 > 1.5 (not sure if this one's required though)
- botocore

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for this. +1 for suggesting and introducing me to 'virtualenv'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you uninstall ansible with apt-get and install it with pip.

```
sudo apt uninstall ansible
sudo apt install gcc python-dev python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade PyCrypto ansible awscli boto boto3 ansible-role-manager ansible-playbook-debugger retry
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Konstantin Suvorov suggest was correct. Boto was not install for root/sudo

Not sure how I did it but **pip** and **boto** were install under the local user at:  `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

When i login as root and try to run **pip** to install **boto** i go the following error:

```
    root$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 637, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 650, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

to find what version of pip root was using I did the following: `$python -c "import pip; print(pip.__version__)`

and found it was pip version **8.1.1**. I then updated the following file:  `$vi /usr/local/bin/pip`

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==9.0.1','console_scripts','pip'
__requires__ = 'pip==9.0.1'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
    )
```

and change all reference of **9.0.1** to **8.1.1**.
This allowed pip to work while logged in as root. I then updated pip using `$"sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip` and the checking with `$python -c "import pip; print(pip.__version__)` shows the correct version for root and ansible user

This meant all pip installed on the box are now the same version. I am sure this is not a good solution and would be better for all users (ansible and root) to point to the same pip install but i am not sure how to do this.

with pip working i was able to install boto and boto3  `pip install boto` and  `pip install boto3`